# copy maverick installable from first mac to second

Tags: macos

Would it be possible to copy the Maverick OS downloaded using another Apple ID on the first Mac to be installed on the second mac using a different Apple ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes.

Once you have downloaded the installer, you won't be asked for an Apple ID on installation. The Apple ID is only requested when the installer is downloaded, either from the Mac App Store or from the Recovery HD.

Comment: Can I download it without the Apple ID from the app store?

Comment: @x10nd No, an Apple ID is required to download something from the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the installer and use it to install on all your computers. You only use your Apple ID when you download the installer.